# Render image from mongo atlas with pug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I am a beginner learning nodejs and I would like to know the right way to  retrieve or render an image from mongo atlas using `pug` and `multer` because I am stuck.

```
const storage=multer.diskStorage({
   destination:function(req,file,cb){
     cb(null,"images");
   },
   filename:function(req,file,cb){
     cb(null,"-"+Date.now()+file.originalname);
   }   
})

const upload=multer({storage:storage});
```

I have the destination folder as images with the pug img src as

```
img(src="/images/#{result.pic}").
```

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){ 
  user.find().then(function(result){
  res.render("home",{results:result})
})})
```

but does not seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [noted in the Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation), the `#{foo}` interpolation syntax is no longer supported in attributes.

Instead of using—

```
img(src='/images/#{result.pic}') // no longer supported
```

—you can use:

```
img(src='/images/' + result.pic) // supported
```

Or, if you have ES6 support, you can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
img(src=`/images/${result.pic}`) // supported
```